# Background transition to remove corner radius

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions

We have a linearlayout that has a background which is partially rounded (only the right side), at a determinate moment we need to migrate that background to a not rounded one, so I thought about using the TransitionDrawable, but for some reason this is not working. This are my files:

R.drawable.bg_right_rounded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="10dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    <corners  android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

R.drawable.bg_blue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
</shape>
```

R.drawable.bg_transition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition  xmlns:android=
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_right_rounded"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_blue"/>
</transition>
```

Then the layout is something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vg_chat_typer_inner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_transition">
    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

Then at a given moment we do:

```
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) layout.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(1000);
```

If I do it in a normal situation it works fine, but when I put that linearlayout inside another linear layout with another one, then it stops working. The situation where it fails is the following one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_transition">
            ....
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0">
            ....
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it because of weight? Why is it not working?

Thanks in advance